# Random Variables: X + Y = Z, I observe empircal distrbutions of X and Z, Want to Infer Y's distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

Random Variables: $X + Y = Z$

I observe empirical distributions of $X$ and $Z$. I want to infer $Y$'s distribution.

I know (I think) that if $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are normal, and I observe $ X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X)$ and $ Z \sim N(\mu_Z , \sigma_Z) $  then I can infer $ Y \sim N(\mu_Y = \mu_Z - \mu_X, \sigma_Y =\sqrt{\sigma_Z^2-\sigma_X^2} )$

And I would replace the means and standard deviations with their sample equivalents.

How can I tackle more general cases? Can I tackle student's $T$ variables? Can I tackle this without making distributional assumptions?

I know I need to fall down some rabbit holes to answer this question, but I'm not sure where to even search for the rabbit holes. Can someone recommend a textbook or area of statistics to look for solutions to this question? Does this problem have a name?

Comment: Do you know anything else about these variables? Do you expect any of them to be independent?

Comment: I would be happy to assume independence, if it makes the problem tractable.

As a first past I would even go so far as assuming they are independent and distributed student’s T. Although, I think in reality they are not symmetric, so I would prefer to handle more general cases.

I’m happy to make simplifying assumptions. Independence is a very benign assumption in my setting. Does that open up options? I honestly just don’t know where to start.

Comment: If $X$ and $Z$ are independent T variables, then $Y$ is generally not expressible in terms of T distributed variables. However a convolution like integral form for it's distribution exists. Also, if you assume that $X$ and $Y$ are independent then you are trying to solve a completely different problem which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Independence is a good simplifying assumption, unless you have information about the JOINT probability distribution of the two variables $X,Z$. You really should specify your assumptions about the problem, because a general solution does not exist unless you have full knowledge of a joint probability distribution...

Comment: I don’t observe anything about the joint distributions.

Comment: Can you explain why independence of X and Y is tougher? 

If X is N(0,2) and Y is independent normal and Z is N(0,4), then Y is N(0,2), but X and Z aren’t independent, right? E[Z | x=2 ] = 2

Comment: In your previous example you assumed $Y$ is a normal distribution. If you only know the form of $X,Z$ then it is not a priori obvious what the distribution of $Y$ should look like. In this case of $X,Y$ independence but only available data for $X,Z$, the problem has to be solved inverting a generally intractable Fourier transform.